# How to represent No-input timeout in Nuance OSDM?

Tags: grammar, voice-recognition, ivr, vxml

I am new to **Nuance OSDM**, I am working on managing timeouts using OSDM.

I am clear with incomplete timeout which occurs between two inputs.

My problem is I need to specify **timeout for No-input**

```
eg., IVR should wait for 100 sec to get input from user, 

If user enters any input with in 100 secs then it has to be validated.

If user not enters any input with in 100 secs then the IVR has to play No-input prompt.
```

Any suggestions are acceptable, Please help me to get my issue out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you searched the manual for the term "timeout" and checked if some of the settings would be the ones you need to change?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming by the tags that you are using for the question that you are using VoiceXML to develop your voice application.  You would use the ***property*** tag to specify the ***noinput*** timeout.

```
<property name="timeout" value="100s"/>
```

You can set the scope of how this is timeout is set dependent on where you place the ***property*** tag. If you put it as a child of the ***vxml*** tag it will have an application scope. If you put it as a child of a ***form*** or ***field*** it will only apply to that ***form*** or ***field***.

If you are using VoiceXML this question is not specific to the speech recognition engine being used.